# Angular-boostrap popover requires Tooltip Module?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

"Like the Bootstrap jQuery plugin, the popover requires the tooltip module."

Is this why I can't get my popover to work? What is the tooltip module, do I need to import something else? I imported bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, angular, and angular-animate. I still can't get something as simple as this to work:

`<button uib-popover="test" popover-placement="top" popover-trigger="mouseenter">test</button>`

The plunker example never imports a tooltip module?

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a part of Bootstrap JS framework. You can enable it by in including either tooltip.js or bootstrap.js files on your page.
https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

As for your issue, it's probably caused by some version conflict between the frameworks -- I had similar problem as yours and managed to get it working by updating the frameworks (AngularJS, bootstrap, ui-bootstrap) to their latest versions.

Also, the popovers don't work on disabled elements (using ng-disabled) (see https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1025 )